# can't get a footer to stay at the bottom of a page

Tags: css, html

The footer on my page at:
http://cinicraft.com/site2.0/index.html

should be below the main content window that says "CONTENT" but I can't seem to get it to go right above the footer that says "CiniCraft (c) 2013 All Rights Reserved"

Here's my code in HTML5:

```
<body>
<div>

<div class="newsBtn">
<h2>News</h2>
</div>

<div class="instaCraftBtn">
<h2>InstaCraft</h2>
</div>

<div class="youTubeBtn">
<h2>YouTube</h2>
</div>

<div class="contactBtn">
<h2>Contact</h2>
</div>

<div class="contentWindow">
CONTENT
</div>

</div>

</body>

<footer>
<div class="dock">
CiniCraft (c) 2013 All Rights Reserved
</div>
</footer>
```

This is the CSS code for the content and footer:

```
div.contentWindow
{
float:right;
text-align:center;
background-color: #000000;
width:900px;
height:900px;
padding:1px;
margin:5px;
}


div.dock
{

overflow-y: hidden;
position:relative;
left:-10px;
background-color: black;

padding:1px;
border:5px solid black;
margin-top: 120px;
}
```

How could I go about getting my footer to stay directly below the content window?
thanks

Comment: Why is your HTML outside of the BODY tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `clear:both` to the footer.

Comment: has no effect to the page

Comment: @MattAndrzejczuk It worked for me, try to give it with using style on the HTML.http://oi39.tinypic.com/eamnmc.jpg
And I didn't think that you are talking about sticky footer, this just makes footer going down.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is called a sticky footer.

This should help:

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Also:

[css-tricks example](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)
[clean sticky footer](https://code.google.com/p/cleanstickyfooter/)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have floated elements. Create a clear div below your `contentWindow` div.

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: doesn't seem to have any effect